# USB IR Receiver for Mac

Tags: remote-control

I have a Harmony 650 Universal Remote, which I love! I use it to control a wide range of devices, among them playing and pausing media on on my Mac. (technically a Hackintosh, but that isn't directly relevant).

The Harmony 650 cannot interface over Bluetooth--only IR. For a while now, I've been using the [Logitech Harmony Adapter for PlayStation 3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00267S7XW) alongside [RemoteBuddy](https://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/) in order to get my remote to be recognized by my computer. One of the things I like about this adapter is its sensitivity--it's able to pick up an IR signal no matter which direction my remote is pointed. Annoyingly, however, the harmony adapter takes around seven seconds to "wake up" after it hasn't been used for a few minutes.

I would like to replace this adapter with a non-Bluetooth, USB IR adapter. However, USB IR adapters seem to be very difficult to find nowadays. Where can I find a USB IR adapter that:

1. Will work with my Mac (preferably via Remote Buddy's [Candelair driver](https://www.iospirit.com/labs/candelair/))
2. Will have similarly great sensitivity to my Harmony PS3 adapter
3. Costs less than $25 ($10 or less is preferable, but $25 is my limit)

Comment: Something based on an Arduino Leonardo or other USB MCU might work, but would basically be a re-invention of the http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/USB_Infrared_Toy

Answer (score 2):

Here is the one of the few that is not discontinued:

- [Irdroid USB IrDA Transceiver](https://irdroid.eu/product/irdroid-usb-irda-transceiver/)

**References**

- [Linux - IrDA USB Dongle Howto](http://www.kynesthesy.org/wiki/MoschipIrDA/)
- [LIRC - Linux Infrared Remote Control](http://www.lirc.org/)
- [Ftdi Usb Ir Transmitter And Receiver Ft232r Usb Rs232 Irda Transceiver - Buy Ftdi Usb Ir Transmitter And Receiver,Usb Irda Serial Adapter,Ftdi Irda Transceiver Product on Alibaba.com](https://wholesaler.alibaba.com/product-detail/FTDI-USB-IR-transmitter-and-receiver_60685753061.html)